# AADAuthenticationFilter called only Once

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I downloaded the Azure AD with spring boot from https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot. Its all nice and works well as long as I run the`azure-active-directory-spring-boot-sample` using

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

as shown in the README file.

I am trying just a basic real-life scenario where the *angular/react app* is running separately on a separate port using npm. The moment I separated them out the main Filter `AADAuthenticationFilter` is only invoked once on the first request where it does token verification and never again for subsequent requests.

I went around and configured an nginx proxy so that the domains of these two are now same 
`localhost:9999` and I redirect based on the next path like `web` for the npm and `app` for the Spring boot. This enabled the cookies to be available at every request.

This helps because what I learned is that Spring uses cookies to maintain a session. But ideally, the AAD filter should revalidate the token every request.

But if I add a property of `azure.activedirectory.session-stateless=true` to my application.properties, as mentioned in the filter's code to make it stateless and validate on every request. It expects roles as a different attribute in AD instead of it being a group of the user.

I also don't understand get the behaviour, when the `js` files are embedded within the spring app and run all this works perfectly fine and the filter is invoked at every request. But when I separate them out it just doesn't work.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that a lot more info may be required for someone to debug the above problem. But I was just able to solve this - at least found the problem that was causing it. Like I mentioned earlier the problem started when I separated the client and spring APIs. And since the client was not able to send back the cookies set by server, due to change in domains I had to put a proxy server.
What I found out later was that every `GET` request was always invoking the AAD filter. Even multiple requests. But other requests like `POST, PUT` were failing. I tried disabling the `csrf` config in spring `WebSecurityConfig.java  -->>  http.csrf().disable();`
This solved my problem and now I receive a request and all works as expected. Now I am trying to figure out how not to disable csrf completely.
Thanks